# Can someone please explain this line of code

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

I was watching a youtube video on how to implement your own vector/dynamic_array in C++.
I understood everything except one like of code, I'm new to c++ and trying to understand the underline data structure implementation.
But I didn't see such a line of code like that one.
The Code:

```
template<typename... Args>
T& EmplaceBack(Args&&... args) {
    if (m_Size >= m_Capacity) {
        ReAlloc(m_Capacity + m_Capacity / 2);
    }
    new(&m_Data[m_Size])T(std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
    return m_Data[m_Size++];
}
```

The line I didn't understand:

```
new(&m_Data[m_Size])T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

What that line of code is really doing ?
Btw, I don't really know what `std::forward` is.
Thx for any explanation. :)

Comment: This use of `new` is called *placement-new*, look it up. As for `std::forward`, look up perfect forwarding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code constructs an object of type T with arguments args... at the address &m_Data[m_Size]. No memory allocation involved.

```
new(&m_Data[m_Size])T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Lets assume we call a "normal" `new` operator:

```
new T((std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

This will allocate memory which size will be equal to sizeof(T) and call a constructor of type T at that memory address. `std::forward` is used in the technique called perfect forwarding. In short: no copies, no moves, no passing in any way - arguments are just given to the constructor as if you called it directly.

But what if you have your memory already preallocated - the main performance boosting point of many containers, like the vector? `Placement new` operator is your friend here. You provide it with the address of the preallocated memory and it only constructs the object. And no `delete` is required later, because you didn't allocate anything with `placement new`!

What about the destruction? Normally destructors are called automatically when you `delete` the object. In this case you'll have to call the object's destructor directly, like this - `t->~T();`

Comment: Any one know what the letter 'm' in m_data or m_size stands for? Why that name is used everywhere :D